# How to test Rails helpers isolated from rspec variables/methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Given a new Rails project with `rspec-rails` added.

Given the following (buggy) Rails helper (in `app/helpers`):

```rb
module MyHelper
  def helper_method(_variable)
    variable.to_s
  end
end
```

Given the spec:

```rb
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe MyHelper do
  let(:variable) { :test }

  it "succeeds" do
    expect(helper_method(variable)).to eq "test"
  end
end
```

This spec does not fail. Although the helper has `_variable` in its signature, but accesses `variable` (which would fail in the running Rails app).

As RSpec includes the helper, the helper has access to `let(:variable)` from the spec and happily uses that.

**Is there a way to make RSpec test a helper in such a way, that it is isolated from the test code?**

I'm aware that I could do:

```rb
require "rails_helper"

class MyHelperTest
  extend MyHelper
end

RSpec.describe "MyHelper" do
  let(:variable) { :test }

  it "succeeds" do
    expect(MyHelperTest.helper_method(variable)).to eq "test"
  end
end
```

But it feels to me that this is such a general issue (often variables in method signatures are called the same as in the test setup) that this should be handled by RSpec already?

---

**Update:** Reproduction script using Rails 7.0.3:

```bash
rails new helper-test
cd helper-test
bundle add rspec-rails
bundle

bin/rails g rspec:install
mkdir spec/helpers

cat > app/helpers/my_helper.rb <<EOF
module MyHelper
  def helper_method(_variable)
    variable.to_s
  end
end
EOF

cat > spec/helpers/my_helper_spec.rb <<EOF
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe MyHelper do
  let(:variable) { :test }

  it "succeeds" do
    expect(helper_method(variable)).to eq "test"
  end
end
EOF

bin/rails spec
```

---

**Update 2:** The following spec fails as it should. The difference is calling the `helper.helper_method` instead of `helper_method` directly.

```rb
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe MyHelper do
  let(:variable) { :test }

  it "succeeds" do
    expect(helper.helper_method(variable)).to eq "test"
  end
end
```

Still not sure though why `helper_method` is available directly.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand how broken test helpers can break not the tests themselves but the running app. Do you mean that you share some code between the core logic and test environment by reusing the same mixins (sounds like shooting your own leg to me)? But even if so, RSpec has nothing to do with that - RSpec knows nothing about custom helpers, matchers and other support stuff (and it should not know about them). And your last snippet is perfectly legit - if you need to isolate a certain mixin for testing purposes it is perfectly fine to "inject" it into some blank slate object...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. `MyHelper` is a Rails helper, i.e. it's production code. I'm trying to write a spec to test that helper. My problem was that `MyHelper` raised an exception in production, but the spec happily passes.

Comment: Are you sure the test in your 2nd snippet doesn't fail? How does `helper_method` become available in the `RSpec::ExampleGroup::<...>` context?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the question with a reproduction script.